# Possible std::forward regression with g++ 6.1 - bug or intended behavior?

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, c++14, perfect-forwarding

g++ 6.1 was recently introduced into Arch Linux's testing repositories, and some of my code that successfully compiled with g++ 5.3.0 does not compile anymore. I've made a minimal example:

[gcc.godbolt.org link](https://godbolt.org/g/73RTHf)

```
// This code compiles with g++ 5.3.0
// This does not compile with g++ 6.1

#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

#define FWD(...) ::std::forward<decltype(__VA_ARGS__)>(__VA_ARGS__)

struct sinker
{
    template <typename T>
    void sink(T&)
    {
    }
};

template <typename T, typename TF>
void caller(T& v, TF&& f)
{
    sinker s;
    f(s, v);
}

template <typename T>
void interface(T& v)
{
    return caller(v, [](auto& xs, auto&& xv) -> decltype(auto)
        {
            xs.sink(FWD(xv));
        });
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    interface(x);
}
```

This is the reported error:

```
: In instantiation of ‘get_impl(T&)::<lambda(auto:1&, auto:2&&)> [with auto:1 = sinker; auto:2 = int; T = int]’:
:25:58:   required by substitution of ‘template<class auto:1, class auto:2> get_impl(T&)
      [with T = int]::<lambda(auto:1&, auto:2&&)>::operator 
      decltype (((get_impl(T&) [with T = int]::<lambda(auto:1&, auto:2&&)>)0u).operator()(static_cast<auto:1&>(<anonymous>),
       static_cast<auto:2&&>(<anonymous>))) (*)(auto:1&, auto:2&&)() const [with auto:1 = sinker; auto:2 = int]’
:19:6:   required from ‘void chunk_fn_impl(T&, TF&&) [with T = int; TF = get_impl(T&) [with T = int]::<lambda(auto:1&, auto:2&&)>]’
:25:25:   required from ‘void get_impl(T&) [with T = int]’
:36:15:   required from here
:27:13: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int’
             xs.sink(FWD(md));
             ^~
:10:10: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void sinker::sink(T&) [with T = int]’
     void sink(T&)
          ^~~~
```

---

Changing:

```
return caller(v, [](auto& xs, auto&& xv) -> decltype(auto)
```

to:

```
return caller(v, [](auto& xs, auto& xv) -> decltype(auto)
```

allows the code to successfully compile.

---

I do not understand why this error is happening, as `xv` is being perfectly-forwarded and the `FWD(xv)` call should produce a lvalue reference. Note that the code worked as intended in g++ 5.3.0 and clang++ 3.7.

[gcc.godbolt.org link](https://godbolt.org/g/73RTHf)

*(Try compiling with multiple g++ versions and changing `auto&&` to `auto&`.)*

**Is this a g++ 6.1 bug?** Or was the code incorrectly compiling with previous versions of g++ and clang++?

Comment: Nothing to do with `forward`. This looks like a frontend bug.

Comment: That `auto&&` means that the lambda is a template, that needs argument type deduction. But so is `caller`. I don't get how this could ever compile, it should be stuck in infinitely recursive argument type deduction. At least according to my primitive understanding of lambdas with `auto&&`. Someone please explain why this should work.

Comment: @T.C. reported as [bug 70942](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70942)

Comment: @sp2danny: why would there be any recursion? `interface` calls `caller`, which calls the generic lambda. The lambda then calls `sink`. There is no loop here. Type deduction only occurs once.

Comment: This seems to only affect captureless generic lambdas with a deduced return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a g++ frontend bug: the issue was reported as [bug 70942](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70942).